# Laravel 4.2 Cannot access Query Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, get

I am using **laravel 4.2** with **nginx**, With a simple Get route, I cannot access Query parameters using **'Input::get('id')'** . also If i try **Request::fullUrl()**, i dont see any query parameters here even though I provided.

my route is :

```
Route::get('user' , 'UserController@show');
```

and in Controller I am just using,

```
Input::get('name');
```

and accessing the routes like:

```
localhost/user?name=foo
```

Nginx Configs are:

```
server {
        listen 80;
       root /home/ubuntu/project/public;
       index index.html index.php;
       server_name  localhost;



       # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(html|ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

       location / {
                # First attempt to server request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
       }

       location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
       }
       error_page 404 /404.html;

       location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 36000;
                include fastcgi_params;
       }

       location /server-status {
              stub_status on;
              access_log off;
              allow all;
       }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you nginx site configuration, you should add `$query_string` like so:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Such a noob mistake by me. Thanks Jerodev. Cheers!

Comment: No worries, I made the same mistake some months ago. That's why I recall the error. ;)

Comment: why don't you mark this as an answer if it has solved your problem @Farhan Salam